# OpenGL render PNG image use linear filter have white border

Tags: opengl, png, filtering

Nearest filter, correct:

[image: nearset]

if use linear filter:

[image: linear]

Why? and how to aviod it.

UPDATE:

If use One and One - SrcAlpha, alpha channel is lost:
[image: update image]

I think this is not premultiplied alpha problem.

In shape margin, pixel color is #FFF, alpha value is 0.0, but still to be sampled... Maybe it is library bug.

Answer (score 2):

It is probably a premultiplied alpha problem: Instead of blending with src_alpha,one_minus_src_alpha blend with one, one_minus_src_alpha.

Comment: I googled and tried, but just ignore the alpha channel, and not become transparent

Comment: I think if it is for this reason, perhaps nearest fliter cannot correct work